# Are Listindex values of a different type than values of a cell from a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

```
'fills the text box with information from Sheet1 according to textbox1 input
Private Sub Autocomplete_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim Last_Row As Long
Last_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
Dim w As Long
For w = 2 To Last_Row

If sh.Cells(w, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value Then
    Me.TextBox4.Value = sh.Cells(w, 1).Value
    Me.TextBox1.Value = sh.Cells(w, 2).Value
Me.TextBox8.Value = w
Exit Sub
End If
Next w
End Sub
```

```
'sets textbox4 and 1 to values clicked on
'this listbox uses the same data from Sheet1
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0) <> "" Then
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
    Me.TextBox4.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

```
'updates record accoring to textbox1 input
Private Sub Update_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim Selected_Row As Long
'finds the record according to the value in Textbox4
Selected_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0), sh.Range("A:A"), 0)
sh.Range("B" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Now, if I use the functions `ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)` and `Update_Click()`, it works perfectly fine, but if I use `Autocomplete_Click()` and `Update_Click()`,
all hell breaks loose. Because the match function `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0), sh.Range("A:A"), 0)` fails to accept `sh.Cells(w, 1).Value`.
Can somebody explain why this wouldn't work? Textbox4 is the same value in both cases Listbox and Cells.

Comment: Do you get an error message?  How many columns is the list box?

Comment: Run-time error '381':
Could not get the List Property. Invalid property array index. There are 8 columns in total